# SVG linear gradient looks pixelated

Tags: html, css, svg, linear-gradients

So I have exported svg background image from sketch and inserted it on the page, but it looks really edgy (banding) in browser. Any tips?

```
    <linearGradient x1="-2.48949813e-15%" y1="50%" x2="100%" y2="50%" id="linearGradient-4">
        <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0" offset="0%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0.02" offset="50%"></stop>
        <stop stop-color="#FFFFFF" stop-opacity="0" offset="100%"></stop>
    </linearGradient>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/duskpoet/t6rzazgs/)

Comment: I think you'll need to explain what you mean by "edgy".

Comment: Are you referring to what is commonly called "banding"? The bands of slightly different shades of colour?

Comment: Yes, exactly! Thanks for notice.